# Can I deposit money in Indian PPF account while living in US

Tags: india, bank-account, retirement-plan

I have been living in US for 2 years and working on H1B visa. I might continue staying here for few more years. Before coming to US, I had opened a PPF account with State Bank of India. My question is, can I continue depositing money every year to PPF account? or is there a law that prohibits me from depositing money in PPF while living abroad as an NRI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I had opened a PPF account with State Bank of India.

If you had opened the account before you became NRI its fine. NRI cannot Open a new PPF Account.

> can I continue depositing money every year to PPF account?

If you already have an PPF account, you can deposit funds into this. Best via transfers from NRE/NRO account.

> living in US for 2 years

Incase you have not deposited into PPF for a given year, you need to pay a penalty of Rs 50 every year and a Minimum of Rs 500 every year. So for 2 years your would need to pay Rs 1100/- to regularize the account. Normal contributions can begin after you regularize.

> continue staying here for few more years

The PPF account cannot be closed, you can make deposits as above. On Maturity [15 years] you are expected to close the account and can transfer funds outside of India via the NRO account.

Comment: Thank you very very much Dheer that was very helpful!!!!